# Teamcity - How to display Cucumber reports in teamcity?

Tags: cucumber, teamcity, cucumber-java

Hi I have my automation test running in Team city and I have cucumber reports generated in target folder.

I have passed target folder as my artifact. I can see my reports are getting generated in my target folder. But how can I see the cucumber reports integrated in Teamcity. I have seen that there is an option for Regression Tests Tab in team city but not sure how to configure. Since I am pretty new to team city is there a way I can get my cucumber reports displayed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you will want to use a plugin. There is a cucumber plugin for teamcity listed [here](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/reporting/):

**Third-party plugins**

- TeamCity - prints Cucumber results in a format for interpretation by a TeamCity build agent.

  - [teamcity_formatter](https://github.com/kevinrood/teamcity_formatter) - Compatible with Cucumber 2.
  - [cucumber_teamcity](https://github.com/ankurcha/cucumber_teamcity/) - Tested with Cucumber 1.3.18 and TeamCity 8.x.

The links give some insight on the plugin setup. You can also install these plugins through the Teamcity GUI by navigating to *Administration > Plugins > Upload Plugin Zip*.

Comment: Hi all is this still relevant in 2022 ? looks like the repository referred to are not in activities